# for i in range just uses last row - openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, range, openpyxl

I am using openpyxl to read an excel sheet. Here is my problematic code:

```
for i in range(3, lastRow):
    exData = {}
    exData["param1"] = sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value
    exData["param2"] = float(sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value) 
    exData["param3"] = float(sheet.cell(row=i, column=3).value) 
    exData["param4"] = float(sheet.cell(row=i, column=4).value)
    exData["param5"] = float(sheet.cell(row=i, column=5).value) 
    exData["param6"] = float(sheet.cell(row=i, column=6).value) 
    exData["param7"] = float(sheet.cell(row=i, column=7).value) 
    exData["param8"] = float(sheet.cell(row=i, column=8).value) 
    exData["param9"] = float(sheet.cell(row=i, column=9).value) 
    exData["param10"] = float(sheet.cell(row=i, column=10).value)
```

The variable lastRow is set to 6. The problem now is that if I print exData it just includes the values of the fifth row. If I print i it says 3 4 5 as it should be. So it is set correctly but maybe not saved correctly? Any ideas?

Comment: There is never a need to write your own loop. `sheet.iter_rows(min_row=3, max_col=10)` is what you want. That, and a dictionary comprehension.

Answer (score 3):

You are overwriting the value in the dictionary (exData) in each iteration of the loop, if you want each value in the dictionary to be a list of that column's value in the three rows you need to reset it as a list and then append those lists.

```
exData = {"param1":[], "param2":[], param3":[], "param4":[], "param5":[],
          "param6":[], "param7":[], param8":[], "param9":[], "param10":[]}

for i in range(3, lastRow):
    exData["param1"].append(sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value)
    exData["param2"].append(float(sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value)) 
    exData["param3"].append(float(sheet.cell(row=i, column=3).value)) 
    exData["param4"].append(float(sheet.cell(row=i, column=4).value))
    exData["param5"].append(float(sheet.cell(row=i, column=5).value)) 
    exData["param6"].append(float(sheet.cell(row=i, column=6).value)) 
    exData["param7"].append(float(sheet.cell(row=i, column=7).value)) 
    exData["param8"].append(float(sheet.cell(row=i, column=8).value)) 
    exData["param9"].append(float(sheet.cell(row=i, column=9).value))
    exData["param10"].append(float(sheet.cell(row=i, column=10).value))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are initializing the dictionary for each loop. Please initialize the dictionary outside of for loop. Or you can use list to store each dictionary using the following code.

```
exDatas = []
for i in range(3, lastRow):
    exData = {}
    exData["param1"] = sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value
    exData["param2"] = float(sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value) 
    exData["param3"] = float(sheet.cell(row=i, column=3).value) 
    exData["param4"] = float(sheet.cell(row=i, column=4).value)
    exData["param5"] = float(sheet.cell(row=i, column=5).value) 
    exData["param6"] = float(sheet.cell(row=i, column=6).value) 
    exData["param7"] = float(sheet.cell(row=i, column=7).value) 
    exData["param8"] = float(sheet.cell(row=i, column=8).value) 
    exData["param9"] = float(sheet.cell(row=i, column=9).value) 
    exData["param10"] = float(sheet.cell(row=i, column=10).value)
    exDatas.append(exData)
```

Comment: This will overwrite data in exData

Answer (score 2):

Every time you go through the loop with `i` set to 3, 4, 5 you are storing the data from the corresponding row in `exData["param1"]` etc. So the second time through overwrites the first and the third time through overwrites the second. That is why your dictionary only contains the values of the last row.

Initialize your dictionary only once, and make the row number part of the dictionary key:

```
exData = {}
for i in range(3, lastRow):
    exData[(i,"param1")] = sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value
```

Answer (score 1):

You are reseting exData each time in loop

```
#outside loop
exData = {}
```

Maybe you can use i as key to save in dict or use other data structure like list and just append

```
#your loop
exData[i] = {"param1": sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you need to initialize your dictionary outside the loop, and use .append. This seems to be a succinct we of doing it:

```
exData = {"param"+str(i+1):[]} for i in range(10)}

for i in range(3, lastRow):
    exData["param1"].append(sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value)
    for j in range(9):
        exData["param"+str(j+2)].append(float(sheet.cell(row=i, column=j+2).value))
```